# onSuccess not triggered when query has staleTime. react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a Form component whose initial data I am setting like so:

```js
 const EditProfileForm: React.FC = ({ section }) => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
        updateProfileReducer,
        PROFILE_INITIAL_STATE,
    );

    const setInitalState = (getApiData: GetUserDetailsQueryResp) => {
        dispatch(
            updateProfileAction({
                data: getApiData.getUserDetails,
                reset: getApiData.getUserDetails,
            }),
        );
    };

   const { data, isLoading } = useGetUserDetailsQuery(setInitalState);
    
   const onChange = (formData) => {
    // update the state by dispatching the data
  }

   return // My component;
}
```

The `useGetUserDetailsQuery` has a **staleTime** set for 1 hour. The stale time is used since,  its a User data.  The user query is used at multiple places in App and I don't want to use to fetch it from the server again and again.

The problem is the onSuccess callback doesn't trigger when query has staleTime, **thus not setting my initialState**.

Any way to avoid this problem (without using useEffect) ?

the query function for reference:

```js
export const useGetUserDetailsQuery = (
    onSuccess?: (stateData: GetUserDetailsQueryResp) => void,
): UseQueryResult<GetUserDetailsQueryResp, ErrorResponse> => {
    return useGraphqlQuery('get-user-details', GET_USER_DETAILS, {
        staleTime: 600000,
        onSuccess: onSuccess,
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`onSuccess` is only triggered when a request is send, but you can use a workaround like this:

```
const EditProfileForm: React.FC = ({ section }) => {
  
  const initDispatched = useRef(false);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    updateProfileReducer,
    PROFILE_INITIAL_STATE,
  );

  const setInitalState = (getApiData: GetUserDetailsQueryResp) => {
    dispatch(
      updateProfileAction({
        data: getApiData.getUserDetails,
        reset: getApiData.getUserDetails,
      }),
    );
  };

  const { data, isLoading } = useGetUserDetailsQuery(setInitalState);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(data && !initDispatched.current) {
      initDispatched.current = true;
      setInitalState(data);
    }
  }, [data])
  
  const onChange = (formData) => {
    // update the state by dispatching the data
  }

  return // My component;
}
```